# PhpStorm Настройка рефакторинга кода

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ide, рефакторинг

Есть вопрос про рефакторинг кода в PhpStorm. Проблема заключается в следующием: если ставить табы, то ide считает их как 4 пробела, можно переключатся стрелками, подскажите это не правильная настройка `Code Style` или особенность данной ide? И вообще можно как-ниубдь это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

По PSR-2 стандарту отступ = 4 пробела.

Вы можете это изменить в меню настроек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]